# I'll read that book in 2 hours

Tags: meaning

**"I'll read that book in 2 hours."**
I'm pretty sure this phrase means that after 2 hours from now I will start reading the book, but I can't stop thinking that it could also means that it will take me 2 hours to read (and finish) that book.
My friend says that for the second meaning the following phrase would be more appropriate:
**"I'll read that book for 2 hours."** Which also makes senso to me, but I get the idea that maybe I won't be able to finish it in just 2 hours.
Could some native speaker elighten me on this problem? Can the first phrase be interpreted in both ways?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are correct that the first is ambiguous.  Your friend is wrong- that sentence means you will read for a length of time of 2 hours, but it says nothing about whether you will finish it in that time.  I’d likely say either, “I can read ***that whole book*** in two hours.” or “It’ll only take me two hours to read that book.”

Comment: I think most people would take it to mean that after two hours time you would have the book completely read.  (Thin book or fast reader.)  "I will *begin* reading the book in two hours" would mean that two hours from now you will start reading.

Comment: @Jim: I'd say the ***for** 2 hours* strongly implies you don't expect to *finish* the book in that amount of reading time (usually, *starting from now*). OP's first version is, as you say, ambiguous, but I pragmatically I think *It'll take me two hours to read it* would be the far more likely intended sense. And if you *did* intend the *Two hours from now I'll start reading it* sense, you might well say *I'll read it in 2 hours **time*** (you'd *definitely* do something like that if you were at all bothered about any possible ambiguity).

Comment: @FumbleFingers- Agreed.

Comment: The most common interpretation of "I'll read that book in 2 hours"—without any other context—would be that it will take two hours to read the book.

Comment: The alternative meaning of "Two hours from now, I will read that book" is on equal footing. In speech the meanings would be distinguished by intonation.

Answer (score 2):

**"I'll read that book in two hours"** generally means that *whenever* you start to read the book, *it will take you only two hours to finish it*; i. e., you are a very fast reader! Otherwise, it would be ambiguous (hard to understand) without additional sentences on either side to give more information about your plans for reading.

**"I'll read that book for two hours"** means that *whenever* you start to read the book, *after two hours have passed you will stop reading it*, without regard to how far along you have gotten in the book.

*As you correctly stated*, the proper sentence is, **"Two hours from now I will start reading the book,"** if that is what you intend to do, *and no implication is made as to how long you will read or whether or not you plan to finish the book in one sitting.*